# Reading and Writing From Same Socket in Flink / Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Good Day

I am receiving data (stream data) through flink/kafka.
The port I am connecting to is the same port I need to write a message back to

TCP/IP -> Flink/Kafka Consumer -> Process Data -> Send Result to kafka topic and back to TCP/IP connection

```
// 1. Connect to TCP Stream (TCP (Socket) -> Kafka Stream INPUT)
val consumer_stream = env.socketTextStream(url, port, '\n')

// 2. Processing Data
.....

// 3. Write result to kafka topic 
consumer_stream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09[String](broker_url, topic_name, new SimpleStringSchema()))

// 4. Send result back to connected url ie.(Ref Step 1 URL) (url+port)
(This is where I need Assistance)
```

Connecting to URL and port works. I receive and process the data
I write to the topic
Now I also need to write back to the same url and port that I am connected to.{Since the Url and Port can send and receive data at the same time}

I got it to write to another port

```
// write to Different PORT
val socket_write: DataStreamSink[String] = out_data.writeToSocket(url, diff_port, new SimpleStringSchema())
```

This works... The problem is trying to write to the same port. When I use the same port that I am reading in from... The flink job fails

Any Ideas

Regards

Comment: Or Should I create a kafka producer with the same url. The problem is the TCP connection allows only so many connections so the idea is to use the same connection to receive data

Comment: If you want to reuse the input TCP connection from the `SocketTextStreamFunction`, then it won't be easily possible, because `SocketTextStreamFunction` does not expose the socket. Opening a new connection and writing the data back should, however, work. What is the exception with which Flink is failing?

Comment: On Flink Job Submission with same port for (Read and Write) these error pop up: 

1)org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Job execution failed.
2) Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed
3) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: These errors don't appear when using different ports for reading and writing... Works on different ports

Comment: Thanks for responding :) @TillRohrmann

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED:" to the title. You indicated the problem was solved by accepting an answer. (If the answer was a good one, you might consider upvoting it as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a customised `SinkFunction` to write the data back to the URL.

```
stream.addSink(new SinkFunction<String>() {
    // initialise the client to send the data
    public void invoke(String value) throws Exception {
        // send here.               
    }
}
```

Or with `SocketClientSink`

```
env.socketTextStream("localhost", 5555).map(x => { println(x); x }).addSink(new SocketClientSink[String]("localhost", 5555, new SimpleStringSchema))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have updated my code above (Last Section of Question) - I am now able to write to a different port, but I cant seem to write to the same port.... Could you provide me with a more detailed code sample in terms of writing to the same port

Many thanks

Comment: @SubZero Based on the comment, I think it may not be caused by Flink. Try to write an simple socket program and write the data back to that URL/PORT.

Comment: I have created a basic app that reads an writes to the same port using scala and it does work.

Comment: My Goal: After receiving Input Stream -> "val consumer_stream = env.socketTextStream(localhost, 4444, '\n')" I want to write out to that socket -> "out_data.writeToSocket(localhost, 4444, new SimpleStringSchema())".

Comment: @SubZero I tested locally with a socket server and Flink Streaming job. It worked well... Here is the sample code: `env.socketTextStream("localhost", 5555).map(x => { println(x); x }).addSink(new SocketClientSink[String]("localhost", 5555, new SimpleStringSchema))`

Comment: Perfect Thank You @David -> Adding the SocketClientSink within the sink and not just writing to the socket works. Highly appreciate your assistance

Comment: Also to note for future reference: Use NCAT instead of Telnet and NC, as NCAT allows for multiple connections

Comment: @SubZero No worry ;) Glad to help.